# How to revert remote directory

Tags: git

I know how to recover a messy local branch and synchronise it with the remote one:

```
git reset --hard origin/develop
```

However, I am not sure about the other way round. How to synchronise a messy remote branch with the local one. What is the equivalent set of git commands as to achieve the latter?

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
git push -f origin develop
```

Comment: But push will merge the local develop to the remote one. What I want is to completely overwrite the remote branch with the local one

Comment: What you want happens, when you push with the `-f` for force.

Answer (score 0):

Force push your local

```
git push origin develop --force
```

Comment: Please have a look at my comment

Comment: If you force push your branch it will not merge with your remote. So this is the right command

Answer (score 0):

You **can not** completely overwrite the history of remote branch.

Create a new branch and push changes to it, delete the old one. Rename the new branch to previous one. That's the only solution to completely overwrite remote branch.

> Force push will not delete the history.

**Be careful with force push**

If you `force push` to a remote branch shared by others, there is a possibility that you will destroy others work.